# What is @q doing?

Tags: macro, command

I accidentally typed `@q` instead of `:q` and the file closed. I checked if I have a macro defined by using `:reg q`. It shows a long string of jibberish.

Is it possible to find out exactly what function `@q` performs on my file?

I have reproduced the behavior. i.e. it always closes the file/buffer.

`:reg q` shows `:q^M:startify<80>kl ....`.

The `<80>kl` bit is repeated 8 times. Startify is obviously a plugin but `^M`, etc., seems odd.

Comment: it performs exactly the gibberish you saw in `:reg q` as if you typed it manually in normal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@q` runs the macro defined in the `q` register.

The content of the `q` register is most probably filled with a previous macro recording started when hitting `qq` in normal mode.

In the `q` register, you have the key code you've hit recording the macro. `^M` is the key code for return. So it starts by `:q<CR>` that closes the current buffer. The `<80>kl` is a key code. On my machine running Windows 10 with an azerty keyboard it is the key code for `<left-arrow>` but it can vary depending of your OS or keyboard layout.

To clean the register you could do either of the following:

- `qqq`: record an empty macro in register `q`
- `:let @q = ""`: reset the content of register `q`.

Comment: I didn't realise vim remembers the macros defined during a session after you quit. I thought maybe you had to put them in the vimrc if you wanted them permanently

Answer (score 1):

`@AnyKey` runs whatever macro that key holds. You may have accidently typed those keys while recording macro in `q` key. To completely erase macro in any key you can type `q AnyKey q`. In your caase `qqq` will clean whatever macro `@q` holds.

Comment: This is a stripped down version of @Vivian De Smedt answer above. Should be closed.